# Google script check mail adres in cell that contains a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to build a validation in this script:

```
if(sheet.getRange("B16").isBlank()) {
errMsgMail;
}
else if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
  htmlBody: body,
  attachments:[blobs]     
  });
}
```

The thing is that Cell B16 is a VLOOKUP formula that shows the mailadres from another sheet/table, and in some cases there is no mailadres.

So if there is no mailadres I should not be able to send the mail.

But in this case B16 is a formula does that mean that B16 is never blank?

Because even if there is a mailadres I still get the errMsgMail

Regards,

Ralph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)) returns a Range, not the contents of the cells within that range. For that you will need to specify the Range, and then use e.g. `getValue()`. See the link and information on the Range object it links to for further information.

What that value will contain if there is no email address will depend on the format of your VLOOKUP formula (e.g., have you wrapped it in `IFERROR(..., "")`). You might also find it useful to check that the value matches a regex.